# python dict and function not working

Tags: python, dictionary

Here are the first 20 lines of my text file, I have such 50K lines.

```
prov_type|prov_type_desc
0|FAMILY PRACTICE/CLINIC
1|FAMILY PRACTICE
2|ALLERGIST
3|DERMATOLOGIST
4|INTERNIST
5|NEUROLOGIST
6|NEUROSURGEON
7|OB/GYN
8|OPTHAMOLOGIST
9|ORTHOPEDIST
10|OTOLARYNGOLOGIST
11|PATHOLOGIST
12|PEDIATRICIAN
13|PLASTIC SURGEON
14|COLON AND RECTAL SURGERY
15|PSYCHIATRIST
16|RADIOLOGIST
17|SURGEON
18|THORACIC SURGEON
19|UROLOGIST
20|ANESTHESIOLOGIST
```

I'm reading like this,

```
ovations = pd.read_csv("Ovations.txt",sep='|',dtype=object)
ovations.rename(columns={'prov_type_desc':'specialty'},inplace=True)
```

I wrote a dictionary in order to match specialty, Here is the dict.

```
options = {'FAMILYPRACTICESELF-REFFERAL' : 'FAMILY PRACTICE',
'FAMILYPRACTICESPECIALIST' : 'FAMILY PRACTICE',
'FAMILYPRACTICE/CLINIC' : 'FAMILY PRACTICE',
'GENERALPRACTICE' : 'FAMILY PRACTICE',
'ALLERGY' : 'ALLERGIST',
'ALLERGYANDIMMUNOLOGY' : 'ALLERGIST',
'ALLERGY&IMMUNOLOGY' : 'ALLERGIST',
'ALLERGY/IMMUNOLOGY' : 'ALLERGIST',
'CARDIOLOGY' : 'CARDIOLOGIST',
'CARDIOLOGYGROUP' : 'CARDIOLOGIST',
'CARDIOVASCULARDISEASE' : 'CARDIOLOGIST',
'COLON&RECTALSURGERY' : 'COLON AND RECTAL SURGERY',
'COLON/RECTALSURGERY' : 'COLON AND RECTAL SURGERY',
'COLORECTALSURGERY' : 'COLON AND RECTAL SURGERY',
'DERMATOLOGYGROUP' : 'DERMATOLOGIST',
'DERMATOLOGY' : 'DERMATOLOGIST',
'ENDOCRINOLOGY,DIABETES,ANDMETABOLISM' : 'ENDOCRINOLOGIST',
'ENDOCRINOLOGY' : 'ENDOCRINOLOGIST',
'ENDODONDIST' : 'ENDODONTICS',
'GASTROENTEROLOGY' : 'GASTROENTEROLOGIST',
'GASTROENTEROLOGYGROUP' : 'GASTROENTEROLOGIST',
'GENETICCOUNSELOR' : 'GENETIC TESTING/COUNSELING CENTER',
'GENETICS,CLINICAL(MD)' : 'GENETIC TESTING/COUNSELING CENTER',
'GENETICS,CLINICALMOLECULAR' : 'GENETIC TESTING/COUNSELING CENTER',
'HEMATOLOGYONCOLOGY' : 'HEMATOLOGY/ONCOLOGY',
'HEMATOLOGIST' : 'HEMATOLOGY/ONCOLOGY',
'HEMATOLOGY' : 'HEMATOLOGY/ONCOLOGY',
'HEMATOLOGYGROUP' : 'HEMATOLOGY/ONCOLOGY',
'HEMATOLOGY-ONCOLOGY' : 'HEMATOLOGY/ONCOLOGY',
'HEMATOLOGY-ONCOLOGYGROUP' : 'HEMATOLOGY/ONCOLOGY',
'HOSPICE&PALLATIVEMED' : 'HOSPICE',
'HOSPITALOP/LAB/XRAY' : 'HOSPITAL',
'HOSPITALIST' : 'HOSPITAL',
'INFECTIOUSDISEASEMEDICINE' : 'INFECTIOUS DISEASE',
'INTERNALMED' : 'INTERNAL MEDICINE',
'INTERNALMEDICINESPECIALIST' : 'INTERNAL MEDICINE',
'INTERNIST' : 'INTERNAL MEDICINE',
'INFECTIOUSDISEASESEPCIALIST' : 'INFECTIOUS DISEASE',
'NEPHROLOGY' : 'NEPHROLOGIST',
'NEUROLOGY' : 'NEUROLOGIST',
'OBSTETRICS' : 'OBSTETRICS AND GYNECOLOGY',
'OBSTETRICS&GYNECOLOGY' : 'OBSTETRICS AND GYNECOLOGY',
'OBSTETRICS/GYNECOLOGY' : 'OBSTETRICS AND GYNECOLOGY',
'OB/GYNGROUP' : 'OBSTETRICS AND GYNECOLOGY',
'OBSTETRICSGYNECOLOGY' : 'OBSTETRICS AND GYNECOLOGY',
'OBGYNECOLOGISTSPECIALTY' : 'OBSTETRICS AND GYNECOLOGY',
'OB/GYN' : 'OBSTETRICS AND GYNECOLOGY',
'OB/GYNSELFREFCAP' : 'OBSTETRICS AND GYNECOLOGY',
'GYNECOLOGY' : 'OBSTETRICS AND GYNECOLOGY',
'ONCOLOGY' : 'ONCOLOGIST',
'GYNECOLOGICONCOLOGY' : 'ONCOLOGIST',
'GYNECOLOGICALONCOLOGY' : 'ONCOLOGIST',
'GYNECOLOGICAL/ONCOLOGY' : 'ONCOLOGIST',
'OPHTHALMOLOGY' : 'OPTHAMOLOGIST',
'OTOLARYNGOLOGY' : 'OTOLARYNGOLOGIST',
'OTOLARYNGOLOGY(ENT)' : 'OTOLARYNGOLOGIST',
'PATHOLOGY' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'PATHOLOGYSERVICES' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'PATHOLOGY,ANATOMIC' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'CYTOPATHOLOGY' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'PATHOLOGY,ANATOMICAL&CLINICAL' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'PATHOLOGY,BLOOD BANKING/TRANSFUSIONMED' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'PATHOLOGY,CLINICAL' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'PATHOLOGY,CYTOPATHOLOGY' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'PATHOLOGY,DERMATOPATHOLOGY' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'PATHOLOGY,HEMATOLOGY' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'PATHOLOGY,IMMUNOPATHOLOGY' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'PATHOLOGY,NEUROPATHOLOGY' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'DERMATOLOGY-DERMATOPATHOLOGY' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'DERMATOPATHOLOGY' : 'PATHOLOGIST',
'PEDIATRICMEDICINE' : 'PEDIATRICIAN',
'PEDIATRSELFREFCAP' : 'PEDIATRICIAN',
'PEDIATRICSPECIALTYIALIST' : 'PEDIATRICIAN',
'PEDIATRICS' : 'PEDIATRICIAN',
'PEDIATRICSSPECIALTYIALIST' : 'PEDIATRICIAN',
'PLASTICANDRECONSTRUCTIVESURGERY' : 'PLASTIC SURGEON',
'PLASTICSURGERY' : 'PLASTIC SURGEON',
'PLASTICSURGERYWITHINTHEHEAD&NECK' : 'PLASTIC SURGEON',
'PSYCHIATRY' : 'PSYCHIATRIST'}
```

I wrote a function like this in order to get the value for the key,

```
def key_in_dic(p):
    return next((options[x] for x in p if x in options), 'Other')
ovations['specialty_adj'] = key_in_dic(list(ovations['specialty']))
```

It is not working as expected, What could be the problem in this?

Here is how, I am getting, It should return Other for Non matching keys whic is `ALLERGIST`, but it is not the case.

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe add, how it is working and highlight the mismatch from how it should?

Comment: updated, please check

Comment: Why don't you use `options.get(x, default='Other')` to specify a default value for nonexistent specialties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Barmar already stated, you can use the `get` method of dictionaries. I think the following should give you what you want:

```
ovations["specialty_adj"] = ovations["specialty"].apply(lambda x: options.get(x, "Other"))
```

Comment: One more help, I want to return `specialty `, if it is not matching, Can you suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Happy to help. Note that you need to have matching spellings for the string comparison here, as `options` contains `FAMILYPRACTICE/CLINIC` but in the data frame it is written `FAMILY PRACTICE/CLINIC` with a space. Depending on what you want to achieve you could try `options.get(x.replace(" ",""), "Other"` in the lambda expression. You should accept this answer as the correct one, though.

Comment: yeah, Thank you, I would do for sure, for non matching record it should return the value of specialty, How to do?

Comment: You should check the documentation for dicts. `get` will return the value for the searched item or a default value which you can specify. So `options.get(x, x)` should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dict.get()` method to specify a default when the key isn't found.

```
def key_in_dict(p):
    return (options.get(x, default='Other') for x in p)
```

Comment: it is giving me `<generator object key_in_dic.<locals>.<genexpr...`, while assigning to new variable into data frame, any changes while calling the function?